# Why was the blue pill necessary to be offered alongside red pill?

Tags: the-matrix

> You take the blue pill - the story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe.

Why was Neo offered blue pill when he could simply walk out of the door to believe whatever he wanted to believe? What does blue pill do?

Comment: Clearly puts him to sleep so he can wake up in his bed none the wiser, the matrix doesn’t work if the people in it know it’s not real

Comment: If he takes the blue pill and immediately wakes up in his bed then he can (possibly) think that all of the things he'd just seen were a dream. That's not a possibility if he knows he was awake the entire time, which he would if he walked out of the door.

Comment: The Blue Pill does nothing, but is required to give Neo the illusion of choice, one of the main themes of the series.